# Can Windows Phone 7 connect to an Exchange server to sync its contacts, calendar etc.?

Tags: windows-phone-7, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

Can Windows Phone 7 connect to an Exchange server that allows the phone to keep its contacts, calendar etc. in sync?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can connect to an Exchange server and sync emails, contacts and calendar. If you are looking at doing this in your WP7 application, you will have write your own code to connect and sync various items. There is no API method or class that will help you build your WP7 application to sync items from an Exchange server. You will be able to use email or phone number chooser task to select items from your contacts. You may also send an email from your app. Currently, an app can't interact with the calendar.

HTH, indyfromoz

Comment: I don't want to build my own app, just to type in some credentials in the phone settings and have it connect to an Exchange server. Is that possible?

Comment: Hi Andrei, Windows Phone 7 does provide with the feature to add an Exchange server account and sync all your items. In your phone, click on 'Settings', then, 'email & accounts' and click on 'add an account', this will take you to a new page where you will see the option of 'Outlook'. Select the option and sign in with your email address & password. You can then change the settings after the entry has been created by clicking on 'Advanced Settings'

Comment: This even works for more than one Exchange server at the same time; you get a separate email inbox and all contacts go into the People Hub, merged.